# How to filter IDs which meet two conditions over another column in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, filter

I have a table looking like this:

| id | country | count | count_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A36992434 | MX | 1 | 2 |
| A36992434 | ES | 1 | 2 |
| A00749707 | ES | 1 | 2 |
| A00749707 | MX | 1 | 2 |
| A10352704 | PE | 1 | 2 |
| A10352704 | ES | 1 | 2 |

I would like to keep the IDs whose column country takes the values ES and MX. So, in this case I would like to get an output showing the following:

| id | country | count | count_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A36992434 | MX | 1 | 2 |
| A36992434 | ES | 1 | 2 |
| A00749707 | ES | 1 | 2 |
| A00749707 | MX | 1 | 2 |

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `countryAgg` dataframe which will contain flags for both `MX` and `ES` by aggregating it at the `id` level and further marking it with [array_overlaps](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap.html) to check against both of the countries

And further utilise [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html) to only filter on `ids` containing both `ES` and `MX` as below -

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
id  country count   count_1
A36992434   MX  1   2
A36992434   ES  1   2
A00749707   ES  1   2
A00749707   MX  1   2
A10352704   PE  1   2
A10352704   ES  1   2
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='\t')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()
+---------+-------+-----+-------+
|       id|country|count|count_1|
+---------+-------+-----+-------+
|A36992434|     MX|    1|      2|
|A36992434|     ES|    1|      2|
|A00749707|     ES|    1|      2|
|A00749707|     MX|    1|      2|
|A10352704|     PE|    1|      2|
|A10352704|     ES|    1|      2|
+---------+-------+-----+-------+
```

#### Array Overlap Marking

```
countryAgg = sparkDF.groupBy(F.col('id')).agg(F.collect_set(F.col('country')).alias('country_set'))

countryAgg = countryAgg.withColumn('country_check_mx',F.array(F.lit('MX')))\
                        .withColumn('country_check_es',F.array(F.lit('ES')))\
                        .withColumn("overlap_flag_mx"
                                    ,F.arrays_overlap(F.col("country_set"),F.col("country_check_mx"))
                                             
                                   )\
                        .withColumn("overlap_flag_es"
                                    ,F.arrays_overlap(F.col("country_set"),F.col("country_check_es"))
                                             
                                   )

countryAgg.show()

+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
|       id|country_set|country_check_mx|country_check_es|overlap_flag_mx|overlap_flag_es|
+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
|A36992434|   [MX, ES]|            [MX]|            [ES]|           true|           true|
|A00749707|   [ES, MX]|            [MX]|            [ES]|           true|           true|
|A10352704|   [ES, PE]|            [MX]|            [ES]|          false|           true|
+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
```

#### Joining

```
countryAgg = countryAgg.filter((F.col('overlap_flag_mx') & F.col('overlap_flag_es')))

sparkDF.join(countryAgg
             ,sparkDF['id'] == countryAgg['id']
             ,'inner'
).select(sparkDF['*'])\
.show()

+---------+-------+-----+-------+
|       id|country|count|count_1|
+---------+-------+-----+-------+
|A36992434|     MX|    1|      2|
|A36992434|     ES|    1|      2|
|A00749707|     ES|    1|      2|
|A00749707|     MX|    1|      2|
+---------+-------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you! but what I want to achieve is to get exclusively the IDs within MX and ES countries. For this example, The last ID has PE and ES, therefore, this shouldn't be in the output.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the same

Comment: Do vote the answer as well if it helped you